# How to continue number of table from paging

Tags: angular

[image: page1]

[image: page2]

i have some problem in table No, the number cannot continue in page 2.After 5 in page 1, i want in page 2 is continue number 5 to 6. **I use Angular 2.**

This is my component.html, i only show the code table

```
<div class="rap">

  <table align="center" class="table table-bordered">

    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th [class.active]="order === 'employeeNumber'"
          (click)="setOrder('employeeNumber')" style="background-color: #165fa7">
        NRP
        <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span>
      </th>

      <th [class.active]="order === 'name'"
          (click)="setOrder('name')" style="background-color: #165fa7">
        Name
        <span [hidden]="reverse">▼</span><span [hidden]="!reverse">▲</span>
      </th>

      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let inspector of allpagingData | filter:filter| orderBy: order:reverse:'case-insensitive'; let i = index">
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{inspector.employeeNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{inspector.name}}</td>
      <td>{{inspector.isActive}}</td>
      <td align="center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ac" routerLink="/inspector/{{inspector.id}}" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        <a class="cc"></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success bc" (click)="deleteInspectorIDs(inspector.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div align="center">
    <ul *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
      <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
        <a (click)="getDataPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
        <a (click)="getDataPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
      </li>
      <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
        <a (click)="getDataPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div align="center">
    <button (click)="getcsvFile()" class="btn btn-success">Download</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

how to continue the number of table?

Comment: if your variable "currentPage" goes from 0 to n-1, {{currentPage*5+i+1}} if it goes from 1 to n {{(currentPage*5+i-4}}

Comment: can you copy paste your answer in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `currentPage` variable of pager to calculate the current serial number. this example assumes your page size is `5`. You can replace it with your dynamic page size if required.

```
   <tr *ngFor="let inspector of allpagingData | filter:filter| orderBy: order:reverse:'case-insensitive'; let i = index">
      <td>{{((pager.currentPage - 1)*5) + i}}</td>
      <td>{{inspector.employeeNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{inspector.name}}</td>
      <td>{{inspector.isActive}}</td>
      <td align="center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ac" routerLink="/inspector/{{inspector.id}}" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
        <a class="cc"></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success bc" (click)="deleteInspectorIDs(inspector.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
```